# WCF REST Service c#

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Service with the following Contract:

```
[OperationContract()]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "pubs/{myupi}?orderby={myorder}&startyear={mystartyear}&deptcode={mydeptcode}", 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]

 //method
        Stream GetMyPublistMethod(string myupi, string myorder, string mystartyear,    string mydeptcode);
```

And I can call it with this:

> > //localhost/RPSDATA.SVC/pubs/'APINK12'?orderby=type

And it works fine. But I don't want to use quotes around `APINK12`. However if I remove them I get:

> > "The exception message is 'Invalid column name 'APINK12'

How can I set things up so that quotes are not required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is checking for a column APINK12 in database and that doesn't exist. Please verify whether the required column exist or not?

Comment: APINK12 is a parameter it doesn't exist as a column name

Comment: Is there any query getting executed on database in this method?

Comment: Yes   

cmdStr = cmdStr +  "upi in (" + myupi + ")";

How obvious!  So wrap myUPI in quotes and I'm in businesss...

Thanks Mahesh

Comment: @NigelBirch Then why don't you post it in the question and torture us. Your answer is `"upi in (\"" + myupi + "\")";`